# Server restarted when I take database backup in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-backup

I have 10 databases in my SQL Server 2008.

If I take a database backup, 8 databases are working just fine.

When I take database backup for the remaining two, at 50% of backup of process, the server automatically restarted. So I am not able to backup.

This is my production server. So please help me.how to fix the bug.

Comment: You can start by looking into Server Log to see the possible reason. If server did not just "died" then it should have left some "comments".

Comment: On these 2 databases run the following and share the results. DBCC CHECKDB WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS

Answer (score 0):

- Remove server from production, switch to backup. Smoething is VERY fishy on that server.
- Do detailed server level analysis. This is NOT A SQL SERVER ISSUE - sql server only uses normal Windwos functions, not even installnig a kernel level driver. User level code can not issue a restart or crash the kernel, so something is wrong with the server.